# Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io

im building a simple chat app with socket io angular 2(typescript) and nodejs as a backend server 
i have this function which works perfectly when i click the connect button

```js
connectUser(name){
  
    
   if (name == null || name == ""){
   return  console.log('you must enter a valid username');
   
   }
   this.username = name;

   this.socket.emit('add-user',name);
   //load connected users in the user-window section
   this.socket.emit('request-users',{data:'request users success'});
   var connecctedUsersListener$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.socket,'users');
   connecctedUsersListener$.subscribe((observer:any)=>{
    this.users = observer;
  },(err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
   },()=>{
    console.log('complet');
   });
  
  //load messages and keep track of Them 
  this.socket.emit('request-messages',{data:'request Messages success'});
  var messageListener$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.socket,'message');
  messageListener$.subscribe((observer:any) =>{
   this.messages = observer;
   
  })

  }
```

however i try to use  bootbox.prompt whenever the user tries to connect so i wrap all the code inside this simple function

```js
addUser(){
  bootbox.prompt('what is your name ',function(name){
  connectUser(name); // this is the function in the first code snippet  

     });
  }
```

i get this wierd error **Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined**
how can i fix that and what is the problem here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calling connectUser from addUser you are doing it from another function (apparently a callback).

Javascript binds '*this*' to that wrapper function you are using, and that function doesn't have a '*socket*' member.

When you call the function *connectUser* from the connect button directly, you are probably calling it inline from the object, thus, '*this*' is bound to the object that does contain the '*socket*' member.

Review the following snippet to have a look on how the "function() { }" wrapper is affecting you:

```
class Whatever {
   socket: { emit: string }

   constructor()
   {
      this.socket = { emit: 'works' };
   }

   doSomething()
   {
      console.warn(this.socket.emit);
   }

   works()
   {
      this.doSomething();
      (() => this.doSomething())();
   }

   doesntWork()
   {
      (function () { this.doSomething() })();
   }
}

let obj = new Whatever();
obj.works();
obj.doesntWork();
```

Basically you can probably just change this:

```
function(name) { connectUser(name); }
```

For this

```
(name) => connectUser(name)
```

and it should work.